# What is the C# equivalent of the stl set?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I want to store some values in a balanced binary search tree using C#.  I looked through the collections in the generics namespace and I haven't found an equivalent of the stl set.

What generic collection can I use?  (I don't want to store key/value pairs... just values.)

Comment: Try with [IESI Collections](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sets.aspx). They're used by NHibernate, so should be good implementations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If you require sorted set, use [`SortedDictionary<T,U>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx). This is implemented using a binary search tree. Admittedly, you will be using 64-bits per entry because you are storing a key-value pair underneath. You can write a wrapper around it like this:

   ```
   class Set<T> : SortedDictionary<T, bool>
   {
       public void Add(T item)
       {
           this.Add(item, true);
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you don't require a sorted set, use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).
3. Otherwise, check out [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/). In particular [`TreeSet<T>`](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet_1.htm). It is a red-black tree and only stores the values.

Answer (score 16):

You could use an [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains **no duplicate elements**, and whose elements are in no particular order.

The capacity of a `HashSet<T>` object is the number of elements that the object can hold. A `HashSet<T>` object's capacity automatically increases as elements are added to the object.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't exactly what you're looking for-- it doesn't use a binary tree, but a hash table. This makes the performance better, so is generally preferred, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Try [RedBlackTree.NET](http://www.bobpinchbeck.com/Portfolio/source_code_vb_red_black_tree.htm). It's in VB but I think it can be easily converted to C#.

And I believe some of the collection type **actually uses a red-black tree internally**. So you might want to [decompile the framework](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) itself and look around for some clues.

I don't think a binary tree can be replaced by a HashSet. Their performance characteristics are different, roughly:

HashSet - O(1) lookup (n) search
Binary search tree - O(log n) lookup O(log n) search

If you want to store the values and later perform a search, you will want to be using a binary tree instead of a HashSet.

Comment: That's true: an STL set is sorted whereas a C# HashSet isn't.

Answer (score 2):

HashSet, but HashSet isn't available in version 2.0 of the framework. If you need something for 2.0 then use Dictionary, and specify a dummy type (e.g. object, int, or bool) for which you supply a dummy value (e.g. null, 0, or false) as the second/value parameter (i.e. use the Dictionary as a set of keys without caring about the associated values).

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but for .NET Framework 4.0 and up use `SortedSet<T>` or `ImmutableSortedSet<T>`.